# Filebeat havesting problems

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, logstash-forwarder

I've been facing a probem since a while now. My filebeat plugin does not harvest the fields that i ask him to harvest in my conf file. I'm using filebeat 7.6.0

My conf:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/user.log
    - /var/log/slapd.log
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["kafka1:9092"]
  topic: 'log'
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 10000000
```

The log output:

```
|2020-02-14T07:55:58.664Z|INFO|crawler/crawler.go:72|Loading Inputs: 1,
|2020-02-14T07:55:58.665Z|INFO|log/input.go:152|Configured paths: [/var/log/user.log /var/log/slapd.log],|
|2020-02-14T07:55:58.665Z|INFO|input/input.go:114|Starting input of type: log; ID: 6297130742941599674 ,|
|2020-02-14T07:55:58.665Z|INFO|crawler/crawler.go:106|Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1,
|2020-02-14T07:56:00.664Z   INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":250,"time":{"ms":8}},"total":{"ticks":390,"time":{"ms":16},"value":390},"user":{"ticks":140,"time":{"ms":8}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":6},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"a601336e-8252-460f-9a25-f05dad5851b2","uptime":{"ms":480275}},"memstats":{"gc_next":8594432,"memory_alloc":5169696,"memory_total":17158072},"runtime":{"goroutines":20}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.21,"15":1.06,"5":0.88,"norm":{"1":0.105,"15":0.53,"5":0.44}}}}}}
```

I've been trying to solve it by making it harvest various files. But without success so far. I always get this `"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably rule out that the issue is not with Kafka output. For testing, set up the FIlebeat [file output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/file-output.html) and check whether you are getting any data or not.

Comment: I tried that, i removed the kafka part and focused only on filebeat ouput. Still no harvesting of the requiered files. I feel like the filebeat can't open the log file to harvest  for some unknown reason.

Comment: Now, rule out the input issue by making sure the filebeat has access to the log files. And also log files has some data in it, at least two lines of data.